# jasper com javaFx não abre pelo jar

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasper

Estou com um problema estranho, fiz uma aplicação com javafx e jasperstudio e ao executar dentro do eclipse funciona perfeitamente. Ao gerar o .jar e executar, funciona, porém se eu remonear o diretório onde estão os fontes, o mesmo para de funcionar. Fiz com que o Java pegasse o local onde está o jasper independente do local de criação do mesmo.
O mais estranho é que não tenho nenhum erro, simplesmente não gera erro. O simples fato de renomear o diretório onde estão os fontes o sistema para.
Não sei nem mais pra onde correr.

```
    @FXML
public void negAtraso() throws IOException, JRException {

    try {
        BusinessDAODB businessDAODB = new BusinessDAODB();
        arquivo = new File("negAtraso.jasper");
        String caminho = arquivo.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(caminho);
        System.out.println(arquivo.getAbsolutePath());
        List<BusinessPojo> negocios;
        negocios = businessDAODB.negAtraso();


        Report report = new Report(caminho, ownerWindow);
        report.printPreview(null, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(negocios));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public class Report {
private JasperReport jasperReport;
private Window ownerWindow;

public Report(String reportFileName, Window ownerWindow) {
    try {
        // jasperReport = (JasperReport)
        // JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.getResourceInputStream(reportFileName));
        jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(reportFileName);
        this.ownerWindow = ownerWindow;
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void export(String fileChooserTitle, String fileName, Map<String, Object> paramMap,
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource) {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle(fileChooserTitle);
    fileChooser.setInitialFileName(fileName);
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PDF files", "*.pdf"),
            new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Excel files", "*.xlsx"),
            new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Word files", "*.docx"));
    File selectedFile = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(ownerWindow);

    if (selectedFile != null) {
        ownerWindow.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);

        String extension = "";
        int i = selectedFile.getName().lastIndexOf('.');
        if (i > 0)
            extension = fileName.substring(i + 1);

        try {
            Exporter exporter;

            switch (extension.toLowerCase()) {
            case "pdf":
                exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
                SimplePdfExporterConfiguration config = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
                config.setMetadataCreator("App name");
                exporter.setConfiguration(config);
                break;
            case "xlsx":
                exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
                break;
            case "docx":
                exporter = new JRDocxExporter();
                break;
            default:
                return;
            }

            exporter.setExporterInput(
                    new SimpleExporterInput(JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, paramMap, dataSource)));
            exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(selectedFile));
            exporter.exportReport();
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JRRuntimeException ex) { // File is being used by another
                                            // process and cannot be
                                            // overwritten
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            ownerWindow.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        }
    }
}

public void print(Map<String, Object> paramMap, JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource) {
    Task<JasperPrint> task = createReportTask(paramMap, dataSource);
    task.setOnSucceeded((WorkerStateEvent event) -> {
        ownerWindow.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);

        try {
            JasperPrintManager.getInstance(DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance()).print(task.getValue(), true);
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.setDaemon(true);
    th.start();
}

public void printPreview(Map<String, Object> paramMap, JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource) {
    try {
        Task<JasperPrint> task = createReportTask(paramMap, dataSource);
        task.setOnSucceeded((WorkerStateEvent event) -> {
            ownerWindow.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);

            JRPrintPreview printPreview = new JRPrintPreview(task.getValue());
            printPreview.initOwner(ownerWindow);
            printPreview.show();
        });

        Thread th = new Thread(task);
        th.setDaemon(true);
        th.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private Task<JasperPrint> createReportTask(Map<String, Object> paramMap, JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource) {
    Task<JasperPrint> task = new Task<JasperPrint>() {
        @Override
        protected JasperPrint call() throws Exception {
            ownerWindow.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
            return JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, paramMap, dataSource);
        }
    };

    task.setOnFailed(event -> ownerWindow.getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT));
    return task;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Tente gerar seu JasperReports desta forma:

```
URL arquivo = getClass().getResource("/companyname/seupackage/arquivo.jasper");
JasperReports jreport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(arquivo);
```

O arquivo jasper deve estar dentro da sua pasta source em algum package. Desta forma mudar o nome do diretório raiz não afeta o jasper.